# Silverstripe Elemental Module redirects to frontend 404 page on element save

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I use dnadesign/silverstripe-elemental 2.x-dev, and Silverstripe 4.0.1.

I created a module for page to hold all pages. This is how i added the extension to HomePage.

```
    XYPage\Model\HomePage:
      extensions: 
        - DNADesign\Elemental\Extensions\ElementalPageExtension
```

This is my HomePageController:

```
    namespace XYpage\Controller;

    use PageController;

    class HomePageController extends PageController
    {
    }
```

This is my HomePageModel:

```
    namespace XYpage\Model;

    use Page;
    use XYpage\Controller\HomePageController;
    class HomePage extends Page
    {

     private static $table_name = 'HomePage';

     /**
     * As our controller resides in a different namespace we have to 
     overwrite this method
     *
     * @return string
     */
     public function getControllerName()
     {
      return HomePageController::class;
     }
    }
```

I changed the template variable to $ElementalArea. I see the expected UI in the BackEnd.

Now if i save an single element in the backend i always get redirected into the front-end to the 404 Page.

When i switch back to the Backend the element is linked to the page.

If i fill in content to the WYSIWYG editor on the Content Element and save it the content gets displayed on the page in the frontend.

If i try to edit that element misses the WYSIWYG editor for the content.

I tried hard to fix this, red the docs but i don´t see what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with BetterButtons & DNADesign Elemental.

Just add this to disable BetterButtons for ElementContent in the meantime.

```
DNADesign\Elemental\Models\ElementContent:
  better_buttons_enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems that I can see immediately:

1: Your YAML configuration is referencing `XYPage\HomePage`, where the class's namespace is actually `XYPage\Model\HomePage`. I suspect this is actually an error in your example rather than your actual project, since you say that the elemental editor is working in the CMS.

2: Your `getControllerName()` method is returning `HomePageController::class` which isn't imported in the class, so it will be resolving to the same namespace as the model (`XYPage\Model\HomePageController`). While [this is the default/expected location](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/4.0.1/code/Model/SiteTree.php#L2714-L2715) for SiteTree controllers, overloading this code means it's all on you! Add `use XYPage\Controller\HomePageController;` to your class definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for not being precise enough the errors that you pointed out are actually only in my question. I am kind of desperate at the moment.

Comment: Right. Please provide an example that can be replicated then.

Comment: How would an example look like? What information is missing?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging i found out what caused this some of that behavior. In my case one problem was that i used unclecheese/silverstripe-gridfield-betterbuttons with elemental.

The next Problem is a react error:[image: Error Message:]